# Rails passing params to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my rails app structure as

```
TestApp 
| app 
____| assets 
____| controllers 
__________| app 
_______________| v1
______________________| mobile_controller
_____ test_controller
____| helpers 
____| mailers 
____| models 
____| views 
_________| test
______________| _form
______________| edit
______________| index
______________| show
______________| index
| bin 
| config 
| custom 
| db 
| lib 
| log 
| public 
|.... 
|....
```

I have two controllers Mobile, Test

Mobile controllers has all the API's

```
class Api::V1::MobileController  < ApplicationController 

    # POST method
    def taskCompleted

        respond_to do |format|

        format.html { redirect_to '/thankyou', :params => params, :isValid => true }            

    end
end
```

When the taskCompleted method is called i want to display a thank you screen
So, i am calling index method in TestController,

```
 class TestController  < ApplicationController 

    def index


    end
end
```

In app/views/test/ i have index.html, where i have HTML content.

But i am unable to receive params, passed from taskCompleted method in mobile controller, in index method of Test controller

Can this be possible?

Or do i need to create views for mobile controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build URL with parameters use Rails helper:

```
redirect_to test_path(param1: 'value', ...)
```

or specify controller and action:

```
redirect_to controller: 'Test', action: 'index', param1: 'value', ...
```

in your case you just make redirect to '/thankyou' URL without parameters.

Comment: This worked for me. But the URL contains parameters, i want the URL to be suffixed as http://hostname/thankyou and any one can read the parameters right? is there any other approach? Can i pass json ?

Comment: No, you can't pass JSON. You can pass parameters as part of URL (i.e. /test/value1) or as parameters (i.e. /test?param1=value). Do you want to protect/encrypt parameters?

Comment: I want parametrs to be passed. And, path should be /thankyou  How  to do it?

Comment: I suppose you could store them all in the session, perhaps in flash. But I think you are making a mistake, fighting with the architecture of the web like this will lead to hard to maintain and hard to understand software.

Comment: May be. I am trying to integrate payment gateway. Gateway will pass me checksum for validation. After validating, i need to render hostname/thankyou page with response parameters in DOM element indicating the status of transaction. So that payment gateway SDK in mobile app, uses it as a trigger to get the control back to the app from payment screen. Struck in accomplishing this simple thing. Any suggestion or help would be really helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it is session, for example:

```
def first
  @first_value = params[:f_name]
  session[:passed_variable] = @first_value
end

def second
  @first_value = session[:passed_variable] 
  @get_value = @first_value
end
```